# the application structure in node.js?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, code-structure, application-structure

I am familiar with Java web containers, where web applications are deployed as `war` files.

I am confused how to deploy CSS, JS, HTML, images (and so on) in Node.js. How does one do this?

I have very limited knowledge of Node.js. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using [express](http://expressjs.com/)

Comment: Take a look at this example to create a node server for serving static files: https://gist.github.com/701407

Comment: thanks all . though i am not very clear since i am used .war . I am assuming the folder structure is of xxx.js format

Comment: @Preethi I use [this structure](https://github.com/Raynos/raynos-blog) for my own blog

Comment: Thanks Raynos , i understand . Any idea on various frameworks available with node.js ? I need to talk with SQL db and i am not sure the existing node.js supports that . Jorgen had mentioned about "expresso" which looks interesting

Comment: @Preethi come talk to the guys [node.js chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/642/node-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://expressjs.com/

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration

app.js

```
app.configure(function(){
  var oneYear = 31557600000;
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneYear }));
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.listen(8888);
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class='hello'>Hello world!</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.css

```
.hello { color: green; }
```

Directory structure:

```
project/
    app.js
    public/
        index.html
        css/
            index.css
```

Run your app: `node app.js`

Go visit your website: `http://localhost:8888`

The directory and file names are arbitrary. Everything is configurable, nothing is complicated. Nobody's trying to keep you tied to a specific directory structure or naming scheme in node, generally speaking.

Go get em, tiger.